# Factory Boy Iterator generates the wrong order

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I use [Iterator](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=Sequence#iterator) to create a strict sequence of values.

```
    class MyModelFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
        class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        django_get_or_create = ("first_field",)

        first_field = Iterator(["value_1", "value_2", "value_3", "value_4"])
        second_field = Iterator("aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc"])
        third_field = Iterator([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

I expect that result should be next:

---

```
    [
      ("value_1", "aaaa", 1),
      ("value_2", "bbbb", 2),
      ("value_3", "cccc", 3),
      ("value_4", "aaaa", 4)
    ]
```

### But the outcome is unpredictable:

```
    [
      ("value_1", "aaaa", 4),
      ("value_2", "bbbb", 3),
      ("value_3", "cccc", 1),
      ("value_4", "aaaa", 2)
    ]
```

And when I use this MyModelFactory as a RelatedFactory two times in row, my database raise an error **duplicate key value violates unique constraint third_field**. Yes **third_field** must be unique. The question is why does this error occur if I use **django_get_or_create**?

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show how you obtain the result you're showing? The output doesn't match what I get on a local example; thus, I think the parts you have omitted in your example play a role here...

Comment: For instance do it in such way: ```[MyModelFactory() for _ in range(4)]```